# Como consultar dados de uma tabela usando INNER JOIN em uma subconsulta no PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo, select, join

Possuo o seguinte `SELECT` para selecionar dados de uma tabela (`chat`) em um sistema de chat:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id_chat = '$chat_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) S WHERE id_chat = '$chat_id' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10
```

O mesmo faz a consulta retornando as últimas dez mensagens para exibi-las em forma decrescente.

Nessa tabela (`chat`), há uma coluna `usuario` onde a mesma representa o `id` do usuário que enviou a mensagem.

Gostaria de, a partir do `id` do usuário que enviou a mensagem, conseguir retornar os dados de tal usuário (tabela `usuarios`).

Exemplo da tabela `usuarios`:

```
id | nome  | foto
1  | Lucas | perfil.jpg
```

Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isso utilizando a consulta acima? `LEFT JOIN`? `INNER JOIN`? E, como fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não sei exatamente qual a estrutura de tabela que você tem mas vamos supor que seja esta

```
tb_usuario
- id_usuario
- nome
- foto

tb_chat
- id_chat
- id_usuario
- tx_msg
- dt_envio
```

### id_usuario sendo rigido e necessario

```
SELECT
    U.nome,
    U.foto,
    C.tx_msg,
    C.dt_envio
FROM
    tb_chat C
    INNER JOIN tb_usuario U ON U.id_usuario = C.id_usuario
WHERE
    id_chat = '{$id_chat}'
ORDER BY
    dt_envio DESC
```

O `INNER` ja restringe a `QUERY` a retornar apenas resultados que possuam id_usuario

#### Exemplo

```
- Lucas     |   perfil1.jpg     | teste msg  | 12/01/2016 08:20:14
- Rafael    |   perfil2.jpg     | teste msg2 | 12/01/2016 08:24:37
```

### id_usuario nao sendo rigido

```
SELECT
    U.nome,
    U.foto,
    C.tx_msg,
    C.dt_envio
FROM
    tb_chat C
    LEFT JOIN tb_usuario U ON U.id_usuario = C.id_usuario
WHERE
    id_chat = '{$id_chat}'
ORDER BY
    dt_envio DESC
```

O `LEFT` diz para dar preferencia para o conteudo da esquerda no caso `tb_chat`, assim
caso não haja o vinculo com `tb_usuario` as colunas pertencentes a ele resebem `NULL`

#### Exemplo

```
-           |                   | teste msg  | 12/01/2016 08:20:14
- Rafael    |   perfil2.jpg     | teste msg2 | 12/01/2016 08:24:37
```

#### Nota

- Se você usar `LEFT` e `id_usuario` deve ser rigido, sera necessario polo no `WHERE`

  ```
  WHERE
      id_chat = '{$id_chat}'
      AND id_usuario IS NOT NULL
  ```

Comment: Acredito que utilizando o exemplo do `INNER JOIN` funcionará, já que sempre haverá vínculo entre as duas tabelas (pois terei que consultar os dados do usuário que enviou o chat, e esse usuário sempre estará presente em ambas as tabelas), porém, como adaptar essa solução à minha `query` existente (presente na pergunta), tendo em vista que terei que retornar as dez últimas mensagens em ordem decrescente?

Comment: @Igor eu não compreendi porque você esta usando uma duas `querys`, sendo que você pode usar apenas a `subQuery`, apara adaptar a minha `query` apenas altera o `SELECT *` e adicione `LIMIT 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Isso depende da view que você vai criar. No caso pode ser um `INNER JOIN` para a tabela chat. Contando que todos os chats tenham obrigatoriamente um usuário.

Segue um exemplo:

```
Select * 
From 'chat' 
INNER JOIN 'usuarios' ON 'chat'.$chave_estrangeira_do_id_entre_aspas = usuarios.id 
ORDER BY 'chat'.'id' ASC LIMIT 10
```

Se quiser mostrar mensagens sem usuários por exemplo não precisa de usuário para o chat nem nada, pode usar o `left join`.

Comment: Todos os chats possuem sim um usuário em todos os casos. E no caso, como essa query ficaria, adaptando-a à minha query atual? `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id_chat = '$chat_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) S WHERE id_chat = '$chat_id' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10`

Comment: Você precisa em Mysql segue como ficaria Select * From 'chat' INNER JOIN 'usuarios' ON 'chat'.$chave_estrangeira_do_id_entre_aspas = usuarios.id ORDER BY 'chat'.'id' ASC LIMIT 10  .. Lembrando que o * no select não é muito bom coloque o que você precisa mostrar, como 'chat'.'mensagem', 'usuario'.'nome'